# Sum column values if the value from next column appears multiple times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

i have a column A with formula values: 1 op, 2 op, 4 op, 9 op, 234 op and another with names corresponding to those values: mike1, mike3, mike8, mike2, mike1. How can i sum the values for each name? i have tried with sumif, count but it just doesn't sum them. I have the formula to show the unique names in alphabetic order but i can't make the sum. Thank you.

```
------------------------------------------
|  A    |  B    |  C    |  D    |   E    |
------------------------------------------
|1 OP   | mike1 |       | mike1 | 235 op |
------------------------------------------
|2 OP   | mike3 |       | mike3 | 11 op  |
------------------------------------------
|4 OP   | mike8 |       | mike8 | 4 op   |
------------------------------------------
|9 OP   | mike3 |       |       |        |
------------------------------------------
|234 OP | mike1 |       |       |        |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That also depends on formatting... the "** OP" cells need to be numerical to sum them

Comment: hi, the format is numerical for column A and for =SUMIF($a$2:$a$79,b2,$b$2:$b$79) it gives 0   and for =SUMPRODUCT((b2:b100=b2)*a1:a100) it gives 0

Comment: No, the format of the column does not matter. What @DirkReichel meant is: the value in A must be only a number, not with alphabetical characters attached to them. E.g. instead of "1 OP", you would need "1" in that cell.

Comment: But there are ways to sum the numbers without having to remove the " OP". The values in column A, are they always in this format? "### XX" (numbers + blank + characters)

Comment: Hi, well if it can be done i can cut OP but the problem is that i can't. the formula for column with OP is:  =IF(ISBLANK('C:\[EXPORT.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C:$C),"",('C:\[EXPORT.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C:$C)) . i have tried with replace but it doesn't work.

Comment: the format is always the same #### XX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dirk said - column A needs to be numerical.  "1" is numerical, "OP" isn't.

Based on the example table you gave this formula would work *if* column A was numerical:  `=SUMIF($B$1:$B$5,$D1,$A$1:$A$5)`

If you wanted column A to be numerical you need to remove the OP text from the cell.  You could display the OP by using a custom number format of: `# "OP"` - the SUMIF formula will work then.

Or you could use this formula to remove the OP from the cell and calculate the number: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=$D1)*(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$5," OP",""))) & " OP"`

Comment: In case it is not always "OP", but some other characters, you could also use: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$B$5=$D1), LEFT($A$1:$A$5, FIND(" ", $A$1:$A$5)-1) * 1) & " OP"`

Comment: I would go the CNF route myself. fwiw, neither O nor P are reserved characters in an EN-US system. The quotes are unnecessary. [Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)

Comment: Oh if it is not "OP", of course the formula should be: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$B$5=$D1), LEFT($A$1:$A$5, FIND(" ", $A$1:$A$5)-1) * 1) & RIGHT(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH($D1,$B$1:$B$5,0),1),3)`

Comment: @Jeeped What is the CNF route?

Comment: @Sun - CNF is **C**ustom **N**umber **F**ormat.